# How to create blank page (.aspx) but with core scripts?

Tags: master-page, application-pages, script

I have created a blank page, but then for example ProccessImn() function or _spPageContextInfo variable is not defined. That is because there are not included .js files links I assume.

But what links I have to include to have really a blank page with just a little functionality such as  ProccessImn() function and _spPageContextInfo variable?

Answer (score 1):

The variable _spPageContextInfo is not defined in any of the js files the SharePoint has in layouts folder. It is a variable defined on almost all the pages of SharePoint. Check view source of any SharePoint page and search for that variable.

ProcessImn() function is defined in _layouts/15/init.js. You can use this sample aspx code to get started.

```
<%@ Page language="c#" enableSessionState="true" %>
<script src="http://site_url/_layouts/15/1033/strings.js"></script> 
<script src="http://site_url/_layouts/15/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script> 
<script src="http://site_url/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>  
<script src="http://site_url/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>  
<script src="http://site_url/_layouts/15/sp.core.js"></script>  
<script src="http://site_url/_layouts/15/init.js"></script>  

<script type="text/javascript">
    ProcessImn();
</script>
```